# javascript resets the css value after a href onclick

Tags: javascript, css, onclick, reset

this is the html line where i call the function:

```
<a href="" onclick="showMe(0);">Oranges</a>
```

and this is the javascript:

```
function showMe (whichClass) {

    var fruitShow = document.getElementsByClassName('fruit')[whichClass];

    fruitShow.style.display = 'inline';    
}
```

it works when i click the link and displays the fruit but it disappears. When the site loads the fruits are all set to display: none, i'm not sure if its reverting back or something else is going on. I have also tried using return before the function call (return showMe(1);)

Comment: You need to show more code or we can't help you. Try creating a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: Is there a question here? What do you *want* to happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clicking the link triggers a reload of the page. Passing an empty value to `href` is equivalent to using the URL of the current page.

There are a couple of ways to prevent the page from following the link:

- Change the `href` value to `"#"`. This will make the page jump scroll to the top though, so you probably have to do the next option either way.
- Stop the default behavior via `event.preventDefault()`. The default behavior is to load the URL. You can prevent that via the [event](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_access.html) [object](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_properties.html):

  ```
  onclick="event.preventDefault();showMe(0)";
  ```

  (note: while this works, there are [better ways to bind event handlers](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/introevents.html))
- **Better yet**: Don't use a link (since you don't link to anything), use a `<button>` instead. You can style it anyway you like with CSS.

Comment: haha as im trying to find out how to post html code on this site, you answer my question, thanks

Comment: The best ans.. **Don't use a link (since you don't link to anything, use a <button> instead.**. Thumbs up..To add it to it, `javascript:void(0)` would also do the job

Comment: @Pilot `javascript:void(0)` would also do the job but it's also a bad solution since that javascript is not doing anything there :)

Comment: +1 for "Better yet…". If the OP doesn't want a link, then one shouldn't be used.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your anchor href from `""` to `#`.

replace

```
<a href="" onclick="showMe(0);">Oranges</a>
```

with

```
<a href="#" onclick="showMe(0);">Oranges</a>
```

Comment: Simply saying "do this" doesn't answer the quesiton (though, to be fair, the OP didn't actually *ask* a question).

Answer (score 0):

Or this

```
<a href="" onclick="showMe(0);">Oranges</a>
```

change to this (prevent jumping)

```
<a href="#void" onclick="showMe(0);">Oranges</a>
```

Just to have a tip more, but as already pointed out, using a button on this situation is a better solution.